# Dynamically Adding Classes in Tailwind with Next.js: Seeking Suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm facing a particular challenge that I’m struggling with.

I set out to create a page builder where I can drag and drop page elements to form the desired structure, and pass classes to components which I can then modify dynamically. I’m using Next.js 13.4 and Tailwind CSS v3.3.3 for this project.

I am aware that Tailwind provides a feature called safelist, where I can add classes. However, is there an approach where I could add classes dynamically without incorporating all of Tailwind’s CSS?Example:

`<section className={${props.className}}></section>`

The following approach to styling is not what I’m looking for:

`{isActive ? 'bg-primary-900': 'bg-amber-200'}`

Any suggestions or solutions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While in development use all of the available tailwind classess if you are unsure how just use the play cdn while in development

`<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`

When the Website building process ended I guess you are compiling the newly craeted website to it's own files. if so then use tailwinds's CLI to generate a minified css file and enject it to the new website code.

at the end you need a automated pipeline to make, eject the minified css file but it's possible

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you don't want to use,

> {isActive ? 'bg-primary-900': 'bg-amber-200'}

You can try this one,

```
const bgColor = ['bg-green-500', 'bg-red-500', 'bg-amber-500', 'bg-black',....]
<div className={`${bgColor[num]} text-white h-screen w-8`}>Hey</div>
```

So, when the value of num changes it will change the background color as well.
Hope it helped.